# Error: Unable to get property '_ScriptLoaderTask' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, telerik, scriptmanager

Why does `Error: Unable to get property '_ScriptLoaderTask' of undefined or null referece` get thrown when trying to close a RadWindow with `ScriptManager` and JavaScript in ASP? **(Internet Explorer 11)**

Our application has 'Save and Close' buttons that have the following **C# code** for the closing logic that is executed after the save has completed:

```
public void CloseWindow()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "close", 
        "CloseModal()", true);
}
```

The `.aspx` page has the following **JavaScript**:

```
function CloseModal() {
    var oWnd = GetRadWindow();
    if (oWnd) {
        oWnd.close();
    }
}

function GetRadWindow() {
    var oWindow = null;
    if (window.radWindow) {
        oWindow = window.radWindow;
    } else if (window.frameElement &&
        window.frameElement.radWindow) {
        oWindow = window.frameElement.radWindow;
    }
    return oWindow;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `setTimeout()` for one second before the RadWindow `.close()` function is called  seems to fix the issue. I believe this allows the `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` just enough time to complete execution.

The following JavaScript is a solution to the problem, and stops the error modal from displaying post 'Save and Close' button click:

```
function CloseModal() {
    var oWnd = GetRadWindow();
    if (oWnd) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            oWnd.close();
        }, 1000);
    }
 }
```